# Creating a db.Sequence with sqalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I'm using postgres 10.5, python 3, flask and sqlalchemy. I'm trying to create a column in a `users` table with the following command

`id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.Sequence('user_id_seq'), primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)`

However, when I run this code and create a user, I get the error: 
`error creating user (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) relation "user_id_seq" does not exist`

How can I create the sequence `'user_id_seq'` programmatically? Is there some way to check if it exists and create it if it does not using sqlalchemy

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you will need to create a code to run when starting the bank. for example:

```
def upgrade():
    op.execute("create sequence user_id_seq start with 1 increment by 1 nocache nocycle")

def downgrade():
    op.execute(sa.schema.DropSequence(sa.Sequence("user_id_seq")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, this just ended up being a problem with the way my database table was previously defined. I dropped the table, ran the code and the sequence existed correctly.